# Is the given statement is true ?1

Tags: real-analysis

.  As   i  was googling  i got this 
 [Let $\{f_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ be a sequence of continuous real valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586601/let-f-n-infty-n-1-be-a-sequence-of-continuous-real-valued-functions-def)   but  didnot understand the option B)

Let $\{f_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$  be a sequence of continuous real valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ which converges pointwise to a continuous real valued function $f$.

Is  following statements are true?

b. If $|f_n(t)|\le |\sin t|$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then 
 $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_\infty^{-\infty } f_n(t) \, dt=\int_\infty ^{-\infty } f(t) \, dt$$

from my view it must be true  as  my thinking is that uniform convergence  implies   pointwise convergence   but converse is not true ....

as f(t) = sint  is uniformly convergent on R

Pliz tell tem solution in detail  as or any good hint easy to understant ....

thanks in advance

Comment: Those improper integrals may not exist at all. Are you considering $f_n \ge 0$?

Comment: Counterexample: $$f_n(t)= \frac{| \sin t|}{n}$$